# webpage freezes but all loops have breaking conditions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a website that lets you play Simon's Game.  But it freezes on my first keypress, which should have started the game. It is probably stuck in an infinite loop but I have given breaking conditions in every loop. What is the problem?

I have added breaking conditions in every place I can think of but I don't get where the issue is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var order_array = [];
    function press(j) {
        $("#" + j).addClass(("play_pressed"));
        //sound
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#" + j).removeClass("play_pressed");
        }, 500);
    }
    function order_add() {
        var jk = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        switch (jk) {
            case 0:
                var j = 'p';
                break;
            case 1:
                var j = 'q';
                break;
            case 2:
                var j = 'r';
                break;
            case 3:
                var j = 's';
                break;
            default:
                var j = 'p';
                break;
        }
        order_array.push(j);
        press(j);

    }

    function order_check() {
        var $k = true;
        $("h1").text("Click the keys in Order!");
        for (var i = 0; i < order_array.length && $k; i++) {
            $(".play").click(function (e) {
                if (order_array[i] != e.target.id) {
                    $k = false;
                }
            });


        }
        if (i < order_array.length - 1) {
            console.log(order_array);
            console.log(false);
            return false;
        }
        console.log(order_array);
        console.log(false);
        return true;
    }

    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        $("h1").text("The game has begun!!");
        var $c = true;
        order_add();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $c = order_check();
        }, 1000);
        while ($c && order_array.length > 0) {
            order_add();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $c = order_check();
            }, 3000);

        }
        $("h1").text("The game has ended!!");
        $("body").addClass("end");

    });
}
)
```

Comment: Your main culprit is probably `while ($c && order_array.length > 0) {` since you're calling this constantly (sure you set a timeout inside of it, but you're running this loop over and over and over again thousands of times a second, starting new timers on top of eachother)

Comment: `setTimeout` schedules a function to run at a different time. Other code around it continues to run unabated. So `$c` never changes from true, within the tight loop you have it in.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably caused by the:

```js
while ($c && order_array.length > 0) {
  order_add();
  setTimeout(function () {
    $c = order_check();
  }, 3000);
}
```

Because you're creating many timers over and over again, with each one overlapping. (I'm not completely sure but I'm pretty sure it is). And inside the

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $c = order_check();
}, 3000);
$c = order_check();
```

If I'm right, never switches to false, so the Timeout function doesn't work. (or i'm dumb).